# Excel botão para escolher

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Eu quero saber se é possível com botões ou lista ou com alguma formula. 
Por exemplo tenho uma lista com nome dos países (Portugal, Espanha, Brasil) e quero que na outra lista só me mostre as capitais desses países.

Exemplo:

Escolho numa lista ou noutra forma qualquer Espanha quero que na outra lista me mostra os locais mais importantes.

```
 Espanha     -->    Madrid
                    Barcelona
                    Sevilha
```

E que consiga selecionar um deles

Comment: O link abaixo pode te ajudar. É possível fazer sem VBA com lista suspensa em cascata. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eVmfCMDc9-A

Answer (score 2):

boas

Dê uma olhada nesse código, veja se funciona:

```
    Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Grains"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Fruits"
    ComboBox1.AddItem "Dairy"
End Sub

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ComboBox2.Clear
    Application.EnableEvents = True

    Select Case ComboBox1.Value
        Case "Grains"
            ComboBox2.AddItem "Cereals"
            ComboBox2.AddItem "Breads"
            ComboBox2.AddItem "Pastsa"
        Case "Fruits"
            ComboBox2.AddItem "Apples"
            ComboBox2.AddItem "Oranges"
            ComboBox2.AddItem "Pears"
        Case "Dairy"
            ComboBox2.AddItem "Cheese"
            ComboBox2.AddItem "Milk"
            ComboBox2.AddItem "Yogurt"
    End Select
End Sub
```

link: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/578055-userform-combo-box-options-based-another-combo-box.html